# Dojo1.8: How do I apply HasDropDown function to dijit/form/ComboBox widget?

Tags: dojo

1. I am not familiar with using dijit/_HasDropDown.

I am building ComboBox widget and have the items filled by store. Once it is filled, I need it to drop down  displaying the items by programmatically.

```
var comboBox = new ComboBox
({
    id: "stateSelectZ",// for its own identity
    value: "California",
    store: stateStore,
    searchAttr: "name"
    }, "stateSelectA"
);
documemt.getElementById("stateSelectA").openDropDown();
```

I am not sure how to do about it.

Do I need to define a module to allow ComboBox to have its drop down accessory?

regard 
Clement

Comment: You don't need hasDropDown. That is for creating your own dropdown'able widgets.

Comment: Thanks but I am not able to cause the comboBox to display the items automatically

Comment: That's probably a store issue... When you say "display the items".. is the store populated correctly? And your issue is just triggering the drop down? You can just called the open manually..

Comment: Yes it is indeed populated if it does not display items automatically as I can see it by manually opening it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you looking for

```
comboBox.toggleDropDown()
```

or

```
dijit.byId("stateSelectA").toggleDropDown()
```

Comment: Thanks! I cannot be thankful enough for you had helped me , not once but twice! Yeah, This is what I have been looking for! Thank you again! I am puzzled as to why openDropDown cannot work. I am getting perplexed as I moved on, fearing that I may face more hurdles.

Comment: opendropDown - Opens the dropdown for this widget. To be called only when this.dropDown has been created and is ready to display (ie, it's data is loaded). Sigh It does not make sense since it does not work. I had been struggling with it since yesterday. Liao!